# Case or If condition in where clause in mysql generatres the #1064 error in sql syntax

Tags: mysql

My mysql query is:

```
SET @PID = 0
SELECT * FROM ProductMaster 
WHERE
CASE WHEN @PID = 0 THEN ID = ID ELSE ID = @PID END;
```

I even tried

```
SET @PID = 0
SELECT * FROM ProductMaster 
WHERE
IF(@PID=0, ID=ID, ID=@PID);
```

generates same #1064 synatx error

Comment: You're trying to do two things at the same time.  So, do you want to _select_ data, or do you want to make an assignment to the variable `ID`?

Comment: I want to select Data based on value received in @PID, I've just set @PID=0 for the testing purpose

Comment: Such a code should be structured in a PROCEDURE or FUNCTION. There you can use variables like you are trying.

Comment: ok let me try using SP

Comment: Hi,@Codtex, thanks it works in SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `CASE` expression like that, but you may rephrase your logic as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM ProductMaster
WHERE
    @PID = 0 OR ID = @PID;
```

### Demo

Comment: I want  the value of select query as, if @PID=0 then all the data is to be  showed else just the value of ID in @PID

Comment: @SwapnilWalunj I have given you this logic (I think).

Comment: Hi, @TimBiegeleisen, I tried using your query in procedure as well as in simple query. using S.P, when I pass 1 as parameter, it still gives all the results instead of just recored whose ID is 1

Comment: I did not give my answer in the context of a stored proc, because your original question was for a regular query.  For a regular query, my logic should be working.

Comment: hi, @Tim.
`set @PID = 1;
SELECT * 
FROM ProductMaster
WHERE ID = ID
OR ID = @PID` . gives me all records

Comment: @SwapnilWalunj This [is working in a demo](http://rextester.com/DNIFO76010), so there isn't much more I can do at this point.

Comment: Glad to help...it can be tough to master MySQL if you're not used to it :-0